# delaying instantiation of a view until value exists

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The `get` function in Backbone does not seem to take a success callback. Is there a way to delay the creation of the view in the code below until I'm sure `self.restaurant` exists?

```
self.restaurant = app.collections.restaurants.get(id);
this.showView( '#main', new app.Views.RestaurantDetailView({model: self.restaurant }) );
```

I can do this

```
if (self.restaurant){
  this.showView( '#main', new app.Views.RestaurantDetailView({model: self.restaurant }) );

}else{ 

}
```

but if self.restaurant doesn't exist then I end up doing something awkward to make it work. I'm thinking there must be an simple solution to this problem that I don't know.

Comment: What's wrong with the second code? It's a perfectly normal thing to do.
Or you can try the following: `this.showView( '#main', new app.Views.RestaurantDetailView({model: self.restaurant || {an_empty_object:false} }) );`

Where `{an_empty_object:false}` is an object/array you can use as a placeholder.

Comment: so you create a view with an empty object? but then how do you replace the empty object with the model once it's ready?

Comment: the problem also is that I don't really know what to do in the else clause while I'm waiting for the query to finish

Comment: Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808261/should-the-backbone-router-or-view-handle-fetching-data-and-displaying-loading-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling get on the collection with the id, I rather created a new model with the id, and then called fetch on the model. Fetch takes a success callback so there's no issue of waiting until the query's finished before creating the view

```
 var restaurant = new app.Models.Restaurant({ id: id });
 var self = this;
 restaurant.fetch({
                success:function () {                           
                        self.showView( '#restaurants', new app.Views.RestaurantDetailView({model: restaurant}) );
                    }

        });
```