# Why should you put custom event listeners under intitalize in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm wondering why you need to put a object.on(event, callback, [context]) specifically within an initialize method in backbone, and not somewhere else?

Is it because the initialize method runs automatically -> and the listener starts to listen automatically for that reason?

Comment: You don't have to but it is usually the only sensible place for it.

Comment: As you may know `initialize` method will be called one of the first on Model or View instancing. So in case you need all objects by specific 'class' listen some event the best place to put this  event attach into `initialize` method

Answer (score 0):

A better way to design a backbone application is to separate data loading code and views construction.

This can be done by using a separate controller(A custom javascript object) that does the data load part i.e, initializing your models or collections. The controller loads the data (models/collections) necessary for a particular view.

The view instance is  then created. Data required for the view can be passed as parameters to the view. One of the better ways is to pass it to use the initialize method which gets invoked automatically during the instantiation of the view.

Also we will expect the view to reflect the changes that model/collection undergoes. Its good to define what events of the model/collection that must be listened to in the intialize method since:

1. You know that it will be called for sure.
2. You know for sure that the event binding will be set, since you can reach a view from more than one way like thru a route or a click event on tabs for instance (though better designing is that you have a center piece of code which handles all the ways you reach a view).
3. Also set the rules for event bindings during the initialization itself.
   You can also refer to the below link that talks about decoupling view from data loading.

[Should the backbone router or view handle fetching data and displaying loading status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808261/should-the-backbone-router-or-view-handle-fetching-data-and-displaying-loading-s)